# How to parse MultiResult object with Couchbase Python SDK?

Tags: python, couchbase

The SDK's `get_multi()` method is working great.
My goal is to return an `array` of the documents requested via that method.
I get the *MultiResult* object back, but have been unable to find a way to parse it.

I've tried just about everything out there with no luck...

Comment: Please include some example code of something you tried.  Ideally, it sets up a problem for others to copy and demonstrate their answer.  Include the expected results as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MultiResult` object is essentially a dict-like object which contains key-result pairs, the key being the document key (or "id"), and the value being a subclass of `Result`.

In this case, the `Result` for `get()` will be a `ValueResult`, which has a `value` property which contains the actual value for the operation.

e.g.

```
for key, result in cb.get_multi(keys).items():
    print "Value is", result.value
```

Comment: The various Result classes are documented at http://pythonhosted.org/couchbase/api/results.html

Comment: That did the trick.  Was missing the .items() piece along with fully understanding dict-like objects. That will teach me to jump from node to Python over night...  :-/